Kafka for auto refresh the microservices
I am doing a local project which has 2 service. config-server (which connects to git and fetch the properties) and a product-service.
Currently , if I update property in config store , I need to do a manual refresh in product microservice which will refresh config-server and updates the prop.
But we cannot do this if we have multiple services. hence my friend suggested me to use dockerized kafka.
Trying from last couple of days to integrate it to my microservices.
Note: my microservices are not dockerized. As I will do it down the line. Now it is not needed in my plan of project.
Here are my codes :
Config-server application.yaml
server:
  port: 8071

spring:
  application:
    name: configserver
  profiles:
    active: git
  cloud:
    config:
      server:
        git:
          uri: "https://github.com/xxxx/swiftcart-config-store"
          searchPaths: "configs/{application},configs/common"
          cloneOnStart: true
        kafka:
          enabled: true
          topic: config-updates
          bootstrap-servers: "localhost:9092"
    bus:
      enabled: true  # Enable Spring Cloud Bus


product-service application.yaml
server:
  port: 8081

spring:
  application:
    name: product-service
  profiles:
    active: dev
  config:
    import: "optional:configserver:http://localhost:8071/"
  kafka:
    bootstrap-servers: localhost:9092
    consumer:
      group-id: product-service-group
      auto-offset-reset: earliest
    template:
      default-topic: config-updates

  cloud:
    bus:
      enabled: true  # Enable Spring Cloud Bus

management:
  endpoints:
    web:
      exposure:
        include: "*"
  endpoint:
    health:
      show-details: always
    refresh:
      enabled: true

springdoc:
  api-docs:
    path: /v3/api-docs
  swagger-ui:
    path: /swagger-ui.html

logging:
  level:
    org.springframework.kafka: DEBUG
    org.apache.kafka: DEBUG


Docker compose.yaml which I created in some other directory
version: '3.8'

services:
  kafka:
    image: confluentinc/cp-kafka:7.2.0
    ports:
      - "9092:9092"
    environment:
      - KAFKA_ZOOKEEPER_CONNECT=zookeeper:2181
      - KAFKA_LISTENERS=PLAINTEXT:PLAINTEXT://0.0.0.0:9092,PLAINTEXT_HOST://0.0.0.0:29092
      - KAFKA_ADVERTISED_LISTENERS=PLAINTEXT://localhost:9092,PLAINTEXT_HOST://kafka:29092
      - KAFKA_OFFSETS_TOPIC_REPLICATION_FACTOR=1
      - KAFKA_GROUP_INITIAL_OFFSET_CONFIG=earliest
    networks:
      - swiftcart_network

  zookeeper:
    image: confluentinc/cp-zookeeper:7.2.0
    ports:
      - "2181:2181"
    environment:
      - ZOOKEEPER_CLIENT_PORT=2181
    networks:
      - swiftcart_network

  kafdrop:
    image: obsidiandynamics/kafdrop:latest
    ports:
      - "9000:9000"
    environment:
      - KAFKA_BROKERCONNECT=kafka:9092
    networks:
      - swiftcart_network

networks:
  swiftcart_network:
    driver: bridge


So what is the problem ?
It is not refreshing the microservices when im refreshing the config-server. It is not even updating config-server.
urls i used to refresh config-server :
http://localhost:8071/actuator/bus-refresh
http://localhost:8071/actuator/refresh
But , if I refresh product-service,
http://localhost:8081/actuator/refresh
Properties will get updated.
Let me know if you have any thoughts on this.

Assuming your problem is config refresh not happening. Note - I have not used Kafka here.
Please check below github code ran today to refesh with actuator on client service without restart.
I had changed author name on github properties  and ran refresh which updated the client cofings and config server configs from github.
Client boot properties :- 
server.port=8080
spring.application.name=a-bootiful-client
spring.config.import=optional:configserver:http://localhost:8888/
management.endpoints.web.exposure.include=*
spring.cloud.config.uri=http://localhost:8888
management.security.enabled=false

https://github.com/Roshanmutha/rcmuthaconfigserver/blob/master/README.md
Boot Config server properties:-

server.port=8888
spring.cloud.config.server.git.uri=https://github.com/Roshanmutha/Configuration
spring.cloud.config.server.git.default-label=master

Full code:
https://github.com/Roshanmutha/rcmutha-configclient - Client using property
https://github.com/Roshanmutha/rcmuthaconfigserver - config serverr
https://github.com/Roshanmutha/Configuration - Github config
$ curl --location --request POST 'http://localhost:8080/actuator/refresh' % Total % Received % Xferd Average Speed Time Time Time Current Dload Upload Total Spent Left Speed 100 39 0 39 0 0 14 0 --:--:-- 0:00:02 --:--:-- 14["config.client.version","auther.name"]
PS: i will try with kafka and post that as well in few days. Thanks

Thank you , Yes , in normal it works. Was stuck with Kafka.
Ultimate goal is to , autorefresh all microservices when we refresh config-server
Current repo without kafka :
https://github.com/yogi3345/swift-cart-config-server
https://github.com/yogi3345/swift-cart-product/tree/main
https://github.com/yogi3345/swiftcart-config-store
